# Proving languages are undecidable

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

Let L5 be the language

{ {G,D} | G is a CFG, D is a DFA, and L(D) ⊆ L(G) }

Show that L5 is undecidable.
Is L5 R.E.? Is it co-R.E.?

I am not quite sure where exactly to start with this. Could someone help me in proving L5 is undecidable

Comment: It's certainly co-re, since, given a CFG, you can enumerate words in the CFG and then check if they are in the DFA. So eventually you'll know if $L(D)\subseteq L(G)$ fails. Since the problem asks to prove that it is undecidable, that would mean you'd need to show that $L_5$ is not r.e.

Comment: I am not sure how to show the L5 is not r.e. Could you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: I don't know either, just pointing you in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

This was first published by Hopcroft in 1969.
See the elegant proof [here](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/hopcroft1969.pdf).